# My PowerShell Script does not work from dotnet application

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, dhcp

I run PowerShell scripts from within my .NET Core 3 web application to perform DHCP server tasks.

This one finds out what ScopeID I should use for a new DHCP reservation. It works perfectly when I run it in PowerShell ISE on the web server. When it runs from the the web application on the same server it always returns null.

```
$DhcpServer = 'MY_DHCP_SERVER'
$IPaddress = '10.140.98.143'
$ScopeId = $null

'PowerShell version: ' + [string]$PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force

$all_scopes = Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName $DhcpServer
if($all_scopes) {
    $number_of_scopes = $all_scopes.Count
    $counter = -1
    $hit_in_scope = $null

    Do {
        $counter = $counter+1
                                         
        If (([version]($all_scopes[$counter]).StartRange.IPAddressToString) -le ([version]$IPaddress) -and ([version]$IPaddress) -le ([version]($all_scopes[$counter]).EndRange.IPAddressToString))
        {
            $hit_in_scope = ($all_scopes[$counter]).ScopeID
        }

    } until ($counter -eq $number_of_scopes -or $hit_in_scope -ne $null)
    
    $ScopeId = $hit_in_scope.IPAddressToString
}

$ScopeId
```

Output in PowerShell ISE:

```
PowerShell version: 5.1.17763.2931
10.140.98.128
```

The log when the same script is run in web application:

```
2022-11-01 13:43:00.643 +01:00 [DBG] results: System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]
2022-11-01 13:43:00.644 +01:00 [DBG] results.Count: 2
2022-11-01 13:43:00.644 +01:00 [DBG] resultString: PowerShell version: 7.0.5
2022-11-01 13:43:00.644 +01:00 [DBG] resultString: 
2022-11-01 13:43:00.674 +01:00 [ERR] PowerShell response is null or empty
```

Here is how I run the script in my application:

```
    private async Task<string> RunPowershellScriptWithReturnStringValue(string script, string errorMessage)
    {
        string resultString = null;

        using (var psInstance = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            var results = await psInstance.AddScript(script).InvokeAsync();
            //psdatacollection<psobject>
            Log.Debug($"results: {results.ToString()}");
            Log.Debug($"results.Count: {results.Count}");
            if (results != null)
            {
                foreach (var psObject in results)
                {
                    resultString = psObject != null ? psObject.ToString() : null;
                    Log.Debug($"resultString: {resultString}");
                }
            }
            if (psInstance.HadErrors)
            {
                Log.Error(errorMessage);
                psInstance.LogErrors();
            }
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(resultString))
        {
            Log.Error("PowerShell response is null or empty");
            Log.Debug("PowerShell script follows");
            Log.Debug(script);
        }
        return resultString;
    }
```

I find it strange that I get two different versions of PowerShell. Both scripts are run on the same server.

Is there a way of specifying what PowerShell version I want to use when I call psInstance.AddScript(script).InvokeAsync()? How?

Or should I change the script so that it works with PowerShell 7.0.5? How?

Target Framework is .NET Core 3.1

Comment: I use nuget package Cake.Powershell ver 1.0.1

Comment: Thanks - I removed my previous comment assuming you were using the native PS libraries from MS :)

Comment: Use `.Invoke()` rather than `.InvokeAsync()` (or complement the latter with `.EndInvoke()` once the async tasks have finished) to get results synchronously. You'd need a different NuGet package to run the PowerShell (Core) edition (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK/)

Comment: When you run another commandlet, does it work as expected ?

Comment: @Julien, actually I guess I do. I also have nuget package System.Management.Automation installed. When I searched my packages for PowerShell I just found Cake.PowerShell. It wasn't me that created this application from scratch.

Comment: @Dudute, I'm asking because when I run a simpler '$r = Get-Process | Select-Object -Last 3; $r;' (I don't have a DhcpServer handy), we get the expected result of seeng 3 processes in the results. 
I'm wondering if there isn't something going on in your PS script in the context of .Net (or the .Net user that is running the script). But also, we would expect to see some errors, unless the 'psInstance.LogErrors()' does not work as expected... Where does this psInstance.LogErrors() come from ? Is it an extension you wrote ?

Comment: LogErrors() is an extension I wrote. I don't get any errors. I get two result strings. "PowerShell version: 7.0.5" and null.

Comment: What does your code show when you run this : Get-Processw ? I want to confirm that you actually see errors there

Comment: When I print $counter after my do-until-loop I get the number of scopes in the DHCP server, which tells me it really finds all scopes. So that part works.

Comment: Here's my log if I change my script to "Get-Process"
2022-11-01 15:20:07.598 +01:00 [DBG] results: System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]
2022-11-01 15:20:07.598 +01:00 [DBG] results.Count: 158
2022-11-01 15:20:07.615 +01:00 [DBG] resultString: System.Diagnostics.Process (agentwrap)
2022-11-01 15:20:07.615 +01:00 [DBG] resultString: System.Diagnostics.Process (CcmExec)
2022-11-01 15:20:07.615 +01:00 [DBG] resultString: System.Diagnostics.Process (CmRcService)
etc.

Comment: Have you tried to run your PowerShell script in a PS7 shell ? Because to your point, it might be the issue here. 
We could also try to run it in PS 5 from .Net if need be but I'd say it would be a step backwards.

Comment: I would really like to run it in PS 5 from .Net but I can't find out how

Comment: As far as I know, your app needs to use .Net Framework 4.5 or higher to be able to execute PowerShell 5 scripts. If you must keep .Net Core 3.1 for your web app, you may have to start an external exe - either powershell.exe directly or a custom .Net 4.5+ executable that can run PowerShell 5 - then contact this external exe from your web app. Otherwise, trying to get the script to run properly in PS7 could be the proper solution in your case

Comment: I have now run the script in a PowerShell 7 shell and I have the same issue there. So as I already  wrote in my question I need help to find the reason why the script doesn't work in PS 7 OR I need help to specify  a lower PowerShell version when I invoke the script from .Net. (And by the way, .Net Core 3.1 is higher than .Net Framework 4.5)

Comment: FYI, when I mentioned a higer version of .Net Framework, I meant in .Net Framework. What you are trying to do by absolutely wanting to run a PS5 script inside .Net Core, is merging 2 frameworks that cannot work together. This is why MS build PowerShell Core, to work in the .Net Core FW. Maybe this article could shed some light https://www.techrepublic.com/article/a-tale-of-two-powershells-which-is-the-right-version-for-you/ (section "PowerShell Core and PowerShell: Major takeaways")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

".IPAddressToString" does not exist in PowerShell 7.
If I just remove all of those, my script works as expected from my .Net Core app on the web server.

(Then it does not work when I run it on my local computer since I don't have PowerShell 7. On the other hand I don't have the DHCP server module locally either. When I run this locally I use Invoke-Command to run the PowerShell commands on the server so I already have a totally different PowerShell script. I guess this will be my solution.)

Comment: I am still interested in specifying PowerShell version when calling PowerShell.Invoke(). Is that possible?

If it is possible I have cases where I could use the same script when I run the application on my computer and when I run it on the server. It would be a lot easier to debug my code then.